# Acknowledgements in an R package

Tags: r, package

In a package, I want to aknowledge someone's intellectual help, who has writen no code.
The question is about the best way to credit this help, as I don't find a role of persons who fits with this case.

In `?person`, and ["Who Did What" (The R Journal)](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-1/RJournal_2012-1_Hornik~et~al.pdf) the person's role closer to what I am looking for are:

> "ctb" (Contributor): Authors who have made smaller contributions (such as code patches, etc) ...
>
> "ths" (Thesis advisor): Thesis advisor ...

But the person whose help I want to aknowledge has writen no code, and this is not a thesis

The answer has came from the [link](https://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html) provided by @Axeman with the full list of roles:

> **Consultant** [csl]
>   A person or organization relevant to a resource, who is called upon for professional advice or services in a specialized field of knowledge or training
>
> **Consultant to a project** [csp]
>   A person or organization relevant to a resource, who is engaged specifically to provide an intellectual overview of a strategic or operational task and by analysis, specification, or instruction, to create or propose a cost-effective course of action or solution

The question has been put on hold, if it is reopen I would like @Axeman to make his comment as an answer, to accept it.

If it is considered proper by someone with enough reputation, it could be tagged as persons, credit or attribution.

Regards.

Comment: I would like to vote this question be moved. However, I'm unsure which exchange network it should be moved to.

Comment: You could make them an author, but with a role that clearly denotes they did not write code. See [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#author) and [here](https://www.loc.gov/marc/relators/relaterm.html).

Comment: @Axeman I know have a goal of listing someone in a package as a [dnc] (dancer)

Comment: It should remain closed I think, but I'm glad I was of help. Perhaps you can ask on academia.stackexchange.com instead.